# Sort CSV with unformatted date

Tags: python, csv

How do I sort the following CSV file with the date from newest to oldest? The dates are unformatted, I know I can format them, But what methods can be applied for both of the conditions?

```
IDN,NAME,Gender,DOJ,JOB ID,SALARY
100,Alpha Fenn,M,17-06-2003,AD_PRES,24000
101,Axpire Ced,F,2-9-2005,AD_VP,17000
102,Winston Cor,M,13-01-2001,AD_VP,17000
103,Relv Dest,M,3/1/2006,IT_PROG,9000
```

Is there any way to sort the whole CSV file with the order of DATE (DOJ)?

```
Sorted_Data = sorted(csv.reader(open('Empl.csv')), key=lambda x:datetime.strptime(x[4],"%d/%m/%Y"), reverse=True))
```

The above code does works but only if the date is well-formatted and It only sorts the one column.

After sorting it should look like this:

```
IDN,NAME,Gender,DOJ,JOB ID,SALARY
103,Relv Dest,M,3/1/2006,IT_PROG,9000
101,Axpire Ced,F,21-09-2005,AD_VP,17000
100,Alpha Fenn,M,17-06-2003,AD_PRES,24000
102,Winston Cor,M,13-01-2001,AD_VP,17000
```

Comment: If the date is not formatted consistently, it's impossible. How would you know if `2006-02-04` should come before or after `3/1/2006`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas` and `sort_values`

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""IDN,NAME,Gender,DOJ,JOB ID,SALARY
100,Alpha Fenn,M,17-06-2003,AD_PRES,24000
101,Axpire Ced,F,2-9-2005,AD_VP,17000
102,Winston Cor,M,13-01-2001,AD_VP,17000
103,Relv Dest,M,3/1/2006,IT_PROG,9000"""))

# Or if you have it in a csv file then use
# df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')

df['DOJ'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOJ'])
df.sort_values(by=['DOJ'], ascending=False, inplace=True)

df.to_csv()
```

output

```
',IDN,NAME,Gender,DOJ,JOB ID,SALARY\n
3,103,Relv Dest,M,2006-03-01,IT_PROG,9000\n
1,101,Axpire Ced,F,2005-02-09,AD_VP,17000\n
0,100,Alpha Fenn,M,2003-06-17,AD_PRES,24000\n
2,102,Winston Cor,M,2001-01-13,AD_VP,17000\n'
```